# Puppeteer moving elements from head to body

Tags: puppeteer

In a file using ESI (edge side includes), `esi:include` elements are being moved from `head` to `body`. The same thing happens if I change `esi:include` into `foo`, or any other non-standard HTML element:

**Before:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <esi:include src="/head.html"></esi:include>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**After:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <esi:include src="/head.html"></esi:include>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this intentional? Can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head#See_also, the following elements are valid for <head>:

<base>, <isindex>, <link>, <meta>, <nextid>, <noscript>, <range>, <script>, <style>, <template>, <title>

All other elements are therefore invalid for <head> placement and are moved to body by the rendering engine.